# FOV difference in different perspectives

Tags: modeling, sculpting

Good evening everyone, currently I'm sculpting a 3d character for unreal engine.
I realized that the form of the head changes in different camera perspectives. I formed the head in frontview but if I change the angle with the mousewheel button the face is looking stretched.

I know there is a setting for Focal Lenght but I'm wondering wich perspective is the final result?
Will the head look in Unreal Engine the same like in Blenders frontview or will it look like the stretched User-Perspective view ?

Thx in advantage.

Comment: Imho it's always better to model and sculpt in orthographic view in order to have the most neutral perspective

Comment: @moonboots no. orthographic it is in on opposite side of this dolly zoom effect. So I suppose the answer is it depends on that type of game you are involved. You should match the typical distance in the game between camera and character with blender's one. But I personally like 90-120F than making characters.

Comment: Additional to the answer by @TheLabCat and what I wrote in the comments there, no matter if you sculpt in orthographic or perspective view and what people might see as better or as personal preference, the thing is, which perspective the "final result" is (if you mean after having it imported in a game engine like Unreal) depends on that software. So basically this is not a Blender question, just a question of which perspective does the game engine use? If you know that, switch Blender to this to get an idea how the final result could look in that game engine.

Answer (score 2):

Using the front and side views automatically sets the viewport into orthographic mode, which essentially has infinite focal length. Orbiting from these views automatically resets the viewport to regular, realistic perspective (aka “perspective” for short). See [the Blender manual page on the difference.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/navigate/projections.html) Most 3D games use regular perspective, though it might not be at the same focal length (Blender defaults to 50mm). Use orthographic for dimension referencing, and not for sculpting. Note that you can toggle orthographic off with the viewport gizmo after moving to a side view.

Comment: Although I agree with you, I guess there is still one problem that remains. Yes, usually in Blender the viewport is perspective if you do not switch to some of the orthographic views and yes, most games / game engines use perspective by default, too. But when you say "regular" perspective for both, it might sound to someone not familiar with all this that the perpective view in Blender and e.g. Unreal Engine would be the same. But is it? Orthographic should look the same in all software, but Blender's perspective uses by default a focal length of 50 mm, is it the same for other software?

Comment: Just to make it clear, I gave a +1 for your answer because it is correct, I'm just playing devil's advocate here because to me it seems the OP (or someone else looking into this later) is probably not so aware of the different effects of focal length. When you say use perspective view for sculpting, it might all look nice in Blender's viewport with 50 mm focal length, but just switch to a camera set to a different focal length (to e.g. wider to get more of a room in the FOV) or import the object in Unreal which might have a different focal length (I don't know) and suddenly all looks weird.